# Wrapping an existing database with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

A product we work with contain a very messy database (it is not our product)

- No primary keys defined
- No foreign keys
- All fields allow null without null having any special meaning
- 400 tables

We often need to write applications that read or write data from the database.

I would like to create a layer on top of the database that make it a bit easier to use in our applications. Ultimately I would like to have a layer that can:

1. Replace null values with default for type ("", 0 etc) when reading
2. Add navigation
3. Use LINQ
4. Export an OData interface
5. Be used in Reporting Services (not very important)

All of this must be done without changing anything in the database, i.e. no views, SP etc.

I have done some experiments with Linq2Sql which seem to work pretty well.
With sqlmetal and some regex magic I create entities which looks like:

```
[Column(Name="Quantity", CanBeNull = true, DbType="Int")]
private int? _Quantity;
...
[Column(Storage = "_Quantity", DbType = "Int")]
public int Quantity {
    get { return _Quantity ?? 0; }
    set { _Quantity = value; }
}
```

and then I manually add needed navigation properties.

Unfortunately it seems like investing in linq2sql is a bad thing to do now. If I want OData I need to go with entity framework. The problem is that entity framework will not work at all if the tables don't have a primary key (and all fields allow null so the designer just show error messages in model)

Any ideas on how to do this?

I understand that it will not be automatic and am willing to invest some time in developing tools and manually edit some things. The database schema is stable and changes only include new columns and tables (i.e. no deletes, name changes or type changes)

Comment: Does the db have any alternative keys? E.g. non-pk unique indexes? Are the fk candidate member columns named in a consistent way, so inferring FKs by name+type is feasible?

Comment: Yes it has unique indexes and most fk candidates are named consistently. It is definitely feasible to use tooling for maybe 80-90% of PK/FK generation.

Comment: Ok, here's a first stab at inferring FK constraints and generating associations in EFv4 models based on inferred FK constraints... http://huagati.blogspot.com/2010/12/inferring-foreign-key-constraints-in.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do OData with LINQ to SQL.

That said, the EF works OK (as well as anything...) without a PK. It's the *designer* which wants to know the PK. So you must either define the EDMX yourself, use Code-First, or make a "fake" DB with real PKs to create your model, then switch to the "no PK" version at runtime.

Comment: Odata with linq to sql seem to be "unofficial". Download a class here and antother one there and hack it together. But compared to creating edmx manually it is probably easier.

Comment: Well, yes, but it's hardly the only option.